# Merge discriminated union of object types in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to merge all properties in a discriminated union of object types?

As an example, suppose I have the following type:

```js
type UnionType = { name: string; } | { age: number; } | { visible: boolean; }
```

Is it possible to then merge these into a single type like this:

```js
// Expect: { name: string; age: number; visible: boolean };
type Props = MagicType<UnionType>;
```

This is essentially the inverse of the `Unionize` type from [`utility-types`](https://github.com/piotrwitek/utility-types#unionizet).

Comment: That's not a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) (a union where each member can be distinguished from the others by a common property with different literal values), it's just a union.  What you are asking for  is (essentially) turning the union into an intersection, which is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type).

Comment: Note that if you actually did merge a discriminated union (e.g., `{type: "circle", radius: number} | {type: "square", length: number}`) this way, you'd end up with an impossible type for the discriminant (e.g., `{type: never, radius: number, length: number}`)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can turn a union into an intersection using the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type), with all the caveats that come with it:

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> =
  (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never
```

If you don't like the way `{ name: string; } & { age: number; } & { visible: boolean; }` looks, you can ask the compiler to reinterpret it as a single object type by using an identity [mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types):

```
type MagicType<U> = 
  UnionToIntersection<U> extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never;
```

This gives you the following output:

```
type Props = MagicType<UnionType>;
/* type Props = {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    visible: boolean;
} */
```

which is what you want.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZwCrmgXigbynAQwFsIAuKAZ2ACcE4BzAbigF8oAfXKA+s-AVyIAjCNWZtOeAG4IKCIQBs+QpEiUE44gLAAoXaEixEKVEgCScYKIoQAxsGRwAPDAB8UTLqhQAFDCgQAB5WcAAmFNxwIFAA-L4A1uQwAJQe7lJICKFQ5HAQUqKpQSHhvj6JUHQAZqJQZqmY6ZmhqXFmOfj5orr6GFAAsjwItuiQLu7Y8I6mFlbUNvaO4wHBEGER1bUA8rFcANoA0pVwUPEQIEhVUFsAuuRbhzesHXkFYj06BtAACtRIYBFsIN6MNRhAXMY0BhXIxdAB6ABUUC+UF+-0BXC83nwxD4VFoDFhOmx3F4uUEInexOxMjkimUqnUml0bARcKAA)